# Shell Scripting Tests

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Dears, i need to test an argument to check if it's a directory, normal file or other kinds of files
as i know anything that is not a directory is a file so i can make a test like

```
br@IBMLC0B2ZJL:/mnt/d/a343$ [ -f gg.sh ] && echo "file"
br@IBMLC0B2ZJL:/mnt/d/a343$ [ -d folder ] && echo "directory"
```

but i just saw a question that requires to check the file if a normal file or not, is there any ideas to test that ??

The original question :
"Write a shell script that accepts a file or directory name as an argument. Have the script report
if it is a regular file, a directory, or other type of file. If it is a regular file, exit with a 0 exit status.
If it is a directory, exit with a 1 exit status. If it is some other type of file, exit with a 2 exit status."

Comment: That's what `-f` already tests. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html for tests for other types of files.

Answer (score 2):

There are [different tests](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) you can apply in bash.

> -f file is a regular file (not a directory or device file)
>
> -d file is a directory
>
> -b file is a block device
>
> -c file is a character device
>
> -p file is a pipe
>
> -h file is a symbolic link
>
> -L file is a symbolic link
>
> -S file is a socket
>
> -t file (descriptor) is associated with a terminal device
> This test option may be used to check whether the stdin [ -t 0 ] or stdout [ -t 1 ] in a given script is a terminal.

But from the original question, you don't need to test these all, just the regular and directory, and everything else, maybe like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="${1:-}"
[ -f "$file" ] && exit 0
[ -d "$file" ] && exit 1
exit 2
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that in *nix based OSes everything is some sort of a file, and accessed thru it's path , i.e. `/proc/pid/....` or `/path/to/file`.  So when a problem asks about normal file, that is where the testing with `-f` help (As your answer carefully shows!). Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 /your/test/target" && exit 123
elif [ -f "$1" ]; then
   echo "file" && exit 0
elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
   echo "directory" && exit 1
else
   echo "other type of file" && exit 2
fi
```

Example:

```
root@debian10:~[0]# touch /tmp/test.file
root@debian10:~[0]# mkdir /tmp/test.dir
root@debian10:~[0]# mknod /tmp/ttyS0 c 4 64
root@debian10:~[0]# /tmp/test.sh
Usage: /tmp/test.sh /your/test/target
root@debian10:~[0]# /tmp/test.sh /tmp/test.file 
file
root@debian10:~[0]# echo $?
0
root@debian10:~[0]# /tmp/test.sh /tmp/test.dir/
directory
root@debian10:~[1]# echo $?
1
root@debian10:~[1]# /tmp/test.sh /tmp/ttyS0 
other type of file
root@debian10:~[2]# echo $?
2
```